# Putting Text in the Search Box. eg- "Search My Site"

Tags: search

I would like to add some text in my blank search box for my blog.

My Blog: www.bornsquishy.com

Current searchform.php code:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
    <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s">
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I no absolutely nothing about php.

EDIT - Here's how I solved the problem:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search My Site" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s">
   <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

From the Codex Docs: The [`is_search()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_search) Conditional Tag checks if search result page archive is being displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
<?php $search_box_term = is_search() ? get_search_query() : 'DEFAULT SEARCHBOX STRING'; ?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $search_box_term; ?>" name="s">
```

So this ↑ shows either `DEFAULT SEARCHBOX STRING` or the searched terms if you´re on a search results page.

---

**EDIT:** Here´s  a filter that you can drop instead into your functions.php file:

```
function wpse50321_alter_search_form( $form )
{
    return '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" >
    <input type="text" value="' . ( is_search() ? get_search_query() : 'DEFAULT SEARCHBOX STRING' ) . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Go') .'" />
    </form>';
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpse50321_alter_search_form', 99999 );
```

Comment: Thanks kaiser, but I'm still kinda lost.  The php code I provided is what came with my theme, and I have the CSS already setup for it.  Is there a way to incorporate the 'DEFAULT SEARCHBOX STRING' into the existing search box code?

Comment: This ↑ _is_ adding a default text to your search box and replacing it with the search string on a search result page. The code isn´t  changing css or anything else. Just the default value of the box. Add it and see what happens.

Comment: I added the code and it created a second search box.

Comment: You have to **replace** your current search box with that. Else: You get two... **EDIT** See update. Now you got a filter also.

Comment: When I remove the original code it removes my search box and leaves me with a search box with the "default..." text in it, but it doesn't do anything, and doesn't conform to my CSS.

Comment: I also offered you a filter. Use this one instead. It got the _same_ ID as in your above showed code.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Kaiser..... I didn't implement your answer, but your effort was much appreciated.

I ended up adding the following to my original code:

    placeholder="Start typing to begin searching."

Comment: Then add this as answer. But be aware: You´re locking out IE and several older other browser versions.

Comment: @kaiser IE isn't _locked out_. It just doesn't get the placeholder. Which is actually better, because a search field should never have a default text. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/19579

Comment: @toscho Starting a comment war? ;) Without kiddin´: Yes, I meant that it didn´t get it, so IE would be _locked out_ from interpreting the `placeholder`. Anyway: +1 for the trac link. Should imho better be an answer.